# Fixing divide by zero error with case statement

Tags: sql-server

I have inherited some code with a divide by zero error.

I keep getting the error and not sure if it is the code or where I am placing it. 
Should this line be added or replace a line?

Tried adding and replacing with this case statement:
CASE WHEN SUM(PREOP_MME) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(PREOP_MME) / SUM(COUNT_CASES) END AS PREOP_MME).

```
SELECT 

PROCEDURE_NM
,SUM(PreOp_MME)     / SUM(COUNT_CASES) PreOp_MME
,SUM(IntraOp_MME)   / SUM(COUNT_CASES) IntraOp_MME 
,SUM(PostOp_MME / PostOp_LOS) PostOp_MME
,SUM(Discharge_MME) / SUM(COUNT_CASES) Discharge_MME
,SUM(TOTAL_OVERALL_MME) / SUM(COUNT_CASES) Overall_MME


FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT 

Spine.LOG_ID
,Spine.SERV_AREA_ID [Service Area ID]
,Spine.LOC_ID [Revenue Location ID] 
,Spine.PRIMARY_PHYS_ID [Provider ID]
,Spine.SURGERY_DATE
,Spine.COUNT_CASES
,Spine.PROCEDURE_NM
,Spine.PostOp_LOS

,(PreOp.SUM_SIG * PreOp.PreOp_MME)          AS PreOp_MME
,(IntraOp.SUM_SIG * IntraOp.IntraOp_MME)    AS IntraOp_MME
,(PostOp.SUM_SIG * PostOp.PACU_MME)         AS PostOp_MME
,DischMeds.DOSE_MME                 AS     Discharge_MME

,(PreOp.SUM_SIG * PreOp.PreOp_MME) + 
 (IntraOp.SUM_SIG * IntraOp.IntraOp_MME) + 
 (PostOp.SUM_SIG * PostOp.PACU_MME) + DischMeds.DOSE_MME as TOTAL_OVERALL
```

Comment: I gues you invert the values. because if `A = 0` then  `A / anything` is also 0 and you wont need a case

Comment: Btw what error are you getting? because in mysql `A / 0` doesnt give error, just return null.

Comment: Are you use the DB is MySql ? alias like `[Service Area ID]` say MSSQL. MySql should looks like `\`Service Area ID\``

Comment: That was a mistake - This is MSSql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check  for the divisor ( denominator)  and not for the divided (numerator) is not equal to 0  so  for the first column you coudl try

```
SELECT 

    PROCEDURE_NM, 
    case when SUM(COUNT_CASES) = 0 
                  then 0 
                  else SUM(PreOp_MME)/ SUM(COUNT_CASES) end PreOp_MME,
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `COALESCE`

Here I build  a small **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d5ad5/8)** as example

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(`value1`) / SUM(`value2`) as _before,
       COALESCE (SUM(`value1`) / SUM(`value2`) , 0) as _after
FROM Table1
GROUP by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

I used the CASE WHEN SUM(FIELD) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(FIELD) / SUM(FIELD) END AS

My error was because I was not accounting for zeros in each instance, only the first. Must be time to go home!

Comment: You dont have to post your answer unless add more relevant information. By accepting scaisEdge answer you are saying that solve your problem.